# How do I make my background into a auto slideshow / carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I would like to put let's say 5 images one at the time as the background of a page, i.e. one image would be displayed for a short period of time (let's say one second each) and then repeat them.

I was wondering if there's a way of doing this with CSS or JS?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you are looking for a full screen background image that elegantly changes with fade effect, you can learn how its done, view the demo or even download the source code at https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. This is pretty easy. You can find the source code [here.](https://codepen.io/JonDevOps/pen/qBWaqvw)

Create a Fullscreen Background Slider with Bootstrap

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <div id="carouselFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">  
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>First slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"> 
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"> 
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
} 
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
} 
.carousel-caption {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  font-size:17px
}
.carousel-caption h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
    html,
    body,
    .carousel,
    .carousel-inner,
    .carousel-inner .item {
      height: 100%;
    } 
    .item:nth-child(1) {
      background: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/HZZKGVVJ6I.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .item:nth-child(2) {
      background: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/D2ROMCUEIV.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .item:nth-child(3) {
      background: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/PU9HHZB5QW.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#carouselFade').carousel();
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan... but for some reason, it is not working yet. Only the third image is displayed without any transition at all. I haven't yet edited the names of the classes, why would you advise this by the way? If those are the ones used by Bootstrap? 

I've also checked the link that you provided but the demo for this code seems to be faulty as it leads me to the main page of Google.

Comment: @MarisabelGonzalez sorry about that. I totally rewrote the code try it now. Also if you click the link above it now takes you to a codepen so you can preview it. Let me know if this works for you or if you have any other issues.

Comment: @sunknudsen looks to have provided a promising answer as well, I upvoted it.

Comment: @MarisabelGonzalez how did it go?

Comment: Looks way better now! Apologies for the late reply... Thanks for your help @w3Develops

Comment: Glad I can help. I wish you much success on future projects. Keep coding daily :)

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps what you are looking for.

https://www.jquery-backstretch.com/

```
$.backstretch([
  "images/outside.jpg",
  "images/garfield-interior.jpg",
  "images/cheers.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```